# Metasploit: Example Exploit for Windows 7 / Windows Server 2016

Tags: metasploit

For testing purposes of a logging solution, I would like to simulate an attack by using Metasploit against a Windows 7 / Windows 2016 server. However, I am struggling to find a reliable exploit that actually spawns a root shell on the victim machine.

Initially, I tried to identify a reliable MSF module to be used during the exploit. I selected windows/http/icecast_header as it seems to be more or less independent of the underlying OS version (Win 7 vs. Win 2016). Thus, I installed the vulnerable Icecast version on the victim machine and configured the MSF module. However, as stated before, I am getting a `Exploit completed, but no session was created.`. On the victim machine, the server simply crashes and I am getting a message "Icecast2win MFC Application has stopped working".

Thus, my actual question is: Do you know of a reliable MSF mdoule that works on Windows 7 / 2016 that I can use for testing purposes?

Thanks,
André

Comment: You are looking for an *exploit* but you should be looking for *something exploitable*. Are you using a vulnerable *version* of Win7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have better luck with Windows 7 than Server 2016. The go-to is [MS17-010](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/exploits/windows/smb/ms17_010_eternalblue.rb#L79). You would need to enable SMBv1 and ensure that it is not patched for that version. You can ensure that it's vulnerable first with Metasploit or `nmap` (`nmap target -p445 --script=smb-vuln-ms17-010`).

For Server 2016, I would recommend looking at a web vulnerability. For instance, you can install Tomcat and then use [Metasploit to upload a malicious WAR file](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/exploits/multi/http/tomcat_mgr_upload.rb). This would produce a shell in the context of the user running the web service.